# Getting the size of the bounding box of selected objects in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on resizing all objects as a whole insize the canvas to fit the canvas. I've already got the resizing to work but the problem is that I need to get the size of the bounding box of selected objects to determine the ratio in the resizing process.

[image]

The picture shows I have 2 objects selected. Now I would like to get the height and width of the box that encloses the 2 objects so I can resize it to fit the canvas. How do I do this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The selection created event is what you're looking for.

```
canvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
  let group = e.target;

  let height = group.height;
  let width = group.width;

  console.log(height, width);
}
```